# Unable to see second host in Nagios server

Tags: nagios

Followed same set of instructions on another host (Xubuntu 16.04) but it seems that is not visible in Nagios Server.

Here is a quick snapshot of nagios server hosts.cfg and services.cfg file.

```
[root@agent2 etc]# cat hosts.cfg
## Default Linux Host Template ##
define host{
name                            linux-box               ; Name of this template
use                             generic-host            ; Inherit default values
check_period                    24x7        
check_interval                  5       
retry_interval                  1       
max_check_attempts              10      
check_command                   check-host-alive
notification_period             24x7    
notification_interval           30      
notification_options            d,r     
contact_groups                  admins  
register                        0                       ; DONT REGISTER THIS - ITS A TEMPLATE
}

## Default
define host{
use                             linux-box               ; Inherit default values from a template
host_name                       jim-Ubuntu1504                  ; The name we're giving to this server
alias                           Ubuntu 16.04               ; A longer name for the server
address                         192.168.1.2          ; IP address of Remote Linux host
}

## Default
define host{
use                             linux-box               ; Inherit default values from a template
host_name                       jim-VirtualBox          ; The name we're giving to this server
alias                           Xubuntu 16.04               ; A longer name for the server
address                         192.168.1.11          ; IP address of Remote Linux host
[root@agent2 etc]# 

[root@agent2 etc]# cat services.cfg 
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               jim-Ubuntu1504
        service_description     CPU Load
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_load
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               jim-Ubuntu1504
        service_description     Total Processes
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_total_procs
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               jim-Ubuntu1504
        service_description     Current Users
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_users
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               jim-Ubuntu1504
        service_description     SSH Monitoring
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_ssh
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               jim-Ubuntu1504
        service_description     FTP Monitoring
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_ftp
        }

define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name                jim-VirtualBox
        service_description     CPU Load
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_load
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name                jim-VirtualBox
        service_description     Total Processes
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_total_procs
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name                jim-VirtualBox
        service_description     Current Users
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_users
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name                jim-VirtualBox
        service_description     SSH Monitoring
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_ssh
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name                jim-VirtualBox
        service_description     FTP Monitoring
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_ftp
        }
[root@agent2 etc]#
```

Not sure what is happening because of which Xubuntu(jim-Virtualbox) is not be able to be seen in Nagios server.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

P.S: NRPE is running on agent.

```
root@jim-VirtualBox:/tmp/nagios-plugins-2.1.1/nrpe-2.15# netstat -nap|grep nrpe
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11019/nrpe      
tcp6       0      0 :::5666                 :::*                    LISTEN      11019/nrpe      
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    46618    11019/nrpe          
root@jim-VirtualBox:/tmp/nagios-plugins-2.1.1/nrpe-2.15# 
root@jim-VirtualBox:/tmp/nagios-plugins-2.1.1/nrpe-2.15#
```

Comment: Well, it seems nagios server is not collection information from agent as there is no information about second agent in status.dat. What could be the reason for that ?

Comment: Moderator, Please close this thread. Problem identified and resolved. Closing brace in hosts.cfg was missing which caused it not to detect. There is another issue but I would investigate that separately.